# Differential geometry for nonlinear control theory

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, control-theory

I am an engineering student and I need to acquire a good understanding of some notions in differential geometry such as manifolds, diffeomorphisms, distributions, etc. I can't find a proper starting path. How should I start to learn the subject from basics?

I need the material to study geometric nonlinear control theory. Any further suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: did you already take vectorial-calculus?

Comment: however there is http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Differential-Engineers-Mechanical-Engineering/dp/0486488160

Comment: Yes, I've passed this course

Comment: had you seen any book on differential geometry for physicists and deeply studied it?

Comment: did you see inside the Doolin-Martin 's book?

Comment: Actually, my primary acquaintance with differential geometry was through the following texts on nonlinear control theory:
1 . "Nonlinear Systems Analysis, Stability, and Control" by Sastry
2. " Analysis and Control of Nonlinear Systems: a flatness based approach" by Levine
But, these texts lack a unified and integrated presentation of the subject.
I saw the book you introduced on Google books, it seem helpful and I want to start studying it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone else in a search comes across this question. If you want to learn it for nonlinear control purposes, *Nonlinear dynamical control system*s by Nijmeijer and van der Schaft gives a nice introduction plus you clearly see where what is used, like Frobenius' theorem. Now if you what learn more about differential geometry I would suggest reading any book by John M. Lee, especially *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*. Then If you want to continue, people like Jerrold Marsden, Hector Sussmann and Andrew Lewis all have fantastic material related to geometric control. Especially the book *Manifolds, Tensor Analysis and Applications* contains, I believe, close to all the mathematics related to control and dynamical systems, from a geometric point of view.

Answer (score 2):

If you are still in search of a good reference, I would advise you the Agrachev & Sachkov "[Control Theory from the Geometric Viewpoint](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-662-06404-7)". The book is quite useful for engineers like me and you, but you need a thorough read of first several chapters.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to start with Isidori's Nonlinear Control I. The book contains the basic theory of differential geometry needed for nonlinear control. In case you need more information regarding differential geometry, take a look at Boothby's Differential Geometry.